# Python вывод строки с точным совпадением

Tags: python, файлы

Вы не могли бы мне подсказать , как я могу сохранить в переменную, нужную строчку из файла содержащую только нужное мне слово

Условно говоря есть такой код:

```
import random
import re

str(input(""))
sub_string = 'AAA'

file = open(r'C:\Users\W\Desktop\python\1.txt', 'r')

lines = file.readlines()

for line in lines:
    if sub_string in line:
        print(line)

file.close()
```

где file содержит список:

```
ABC:AAA11
CAB:AAA22
BGG1:AAA
BGG2:AAA
BGG3:AAA
BGG4:AAA
```

в sub_string содержится то, что будет введено в input

далее в переменную сохранить строчку из файла, только содержащую целое слово, в данном примере 'AAA'. Если в файле содержится несколько строк содержащих AAA,то пусть выводится рандомное из всех подходящих.

исходя из списка в файла, в переменную должно быть выведено одно из:

```
BGG1:AAA
BGG2:AAA
BGG3:AAA
BGG4:AAA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все строки соберите в список из которого выберите случайную строку.
Из всех строк надо удалить концы (`strip`), разбить из по двоеточиям, последний фрагмент сравнить с искомым:

```
search = 'AAA'

found = [line for line in file if search == line.strip().split(':')[-1]]
print(found)
if found:
    print(random.choice(found))
```

Comment: Да, изящно, хоть и сложновато для чтения:-) Проверку хорошо бы добавить только `if found` на случай если ничего не найдено, а то ошибку выдаёт.

Comment: А для чего `search in line`, как у автора, надо менять на больший `search == line.strip().split(':')[-1]`? C ней вполне работает, а смотрится она проще, разве нет?

Comment: @Сергей,  смотрите "строчку из файла, только содержащую целое слово" и пример в конце вопроса. Просто `in` не работает как надо.

Comment: А, спасибо, ясно, пропустил это. Просто модифицировал имеющуюся программу. Не обратил внитмания на "есть такой код" (= ''не я писал, исправьте мне его, пожалуйста" :-))

Comment: Спасибо большое, ваше решение мне очень помогло .